# Stanford CoreNLP error processing typos in numbers

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I'm processing text data with Stanford CoreNLP (using Python), and got an error that stopped the program running when it hit the terms "sixth-eight" and "sixth-three."

Here's the error message:
Error interpreting number sixth-eight: Error in wordToNumber function.
Error interpreting number sixth-three: Error in wordToNumber function.

Does anyone know the best way around this? I imagine it happened because the terms look like numbers but then don't compute as numbers given the typos. I don't want the program to halt whenever it hits a number typo.